# How can I convert an Asset object to a File object?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<Asset> imgList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 30,
    enableCamera: true,
  );
```

Is there any way to convert `List<Asset> imgList` to `List<File> imgList`?

anyone???

Answer (score 0):

Like

```
File _file = File(//a file path);
```

i guess there will be definitely be a method to get the file path from the picked assets like

```
Asset.path
Asset.getPath()
Asset.name etc
```

if you need a list

```
List<File> _list = assetList.map((asset){return File(asset.path)});
```